# How to fix SPF issue

Tags: email, dns, cloudflare, spf

So I'm using mail-tester.com, which is great, except now I'm royally confused. The first time I ran a test, here's what it said (in the SPF section, where the problem is that: **You are not allowed to use one of your sender email addresses**)

```
What we retained as your current SPF record is:
  v=spf1 a mx ~all

It should be changed to:
  v=spf1 a mx ip4:some-ip-address ~all

Need guidance? Visit the guide for cloudflare.
```

When I clicked the link to the guide for CloudFlare, it literally said my new TXT record should be `v=spf1 a mx ~all`, which basically contradicted the previous page. So... perhaps the initial diagnostics page was specific guidance while the guide for CloudFlare was just general guidance, on where to put the record? Anyway, so I didn't have a `TXT` record with `v=spf1 a mx ~all` in CloudFlare (unusual again given the previous page said it had retained a SPF record as such), so I added it. It didn't do anything to fix my score.

So what I thought then was, OK let's follow the diagnostic's page's specific guidance and add the IP address. The next time I ran a test, I got:

```
What we retained as your current SPF record is:
  v=spf1 a mx ip4:some-ip-address ~all

It should be changed to:
  v=spf1 a mx ip4:some-ip-address ip4:different-ip-address ~all

Need guidance? Visit the guide for cloudflare.
```

And... you guessed it, following these instructions continually just gets me to a never ending cycle of new ip addresses being added to the record, but nothing actually changing my score. Like, now I'm at:

```
What we retained as your current SPF record is:
  v=spf1 a mx ip4:some-ip-address ip4:different-ip-address ~all

It should be changed to:
  v=spf1 a mx ip4:some-ip-address ip4:different-ip-address ip4:another-ip-address ~all

Need guidance? Visit the guide for cloudflare.
```

Has anyone else had experience with this? If you can't tell, I'm a total noob to SPF and have no idea how to fix this honestly. For context, My domain and mail are managed by Gandi, but redirected through CloudFlare, so CloudFlare is where my DNS records are actually kept.

Comment: Give http://www.spfwizard.net/ a try.

Comment: thanks @Jules. it recommended to do TXT `v=spf1 mx a`, which is what i already have. UNLESS mail-tester's diagnostics can't be trusted... (i.e., in which case `v=spf1 mx a` may be working just fine)

Comment: That's not right, it should be a much bigger string. You have to fill in all the entries. For the Strictness, use SoftFail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say this:

```
v=spf1 a mx ~all
```

It says that the IP that resolves from your domain's A record, and any of the IPs designated as mail exchangers for your domain will receive an SPF `pass` status, and everything else will receive a `softfail`.

So, when you're getting that error, it means you're sending from somewhere that is not covered by that list of permitted sources, and so it's suggesting you add the sending IP to your record to allow it.

If you are sending from somewhere like gmail with a large pool of mail servers, the source address will change frequently, which would explain why it suggests a different IP each time.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Don't send using the external service and really send *only* from the IPs that you designate explicitly (i.e. that are covered by your `a` and `mx` options).
2. Use an SPF `include` directive to allow sending from a source that uses dynamic sending IPs.

In this latter case you would make your record something like:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

While you say you're using cloudflare and gandi, you don't say where you're actually sending email from - if you're not using gmail then `include` the SPF from whichever other service you are using.

**Update**. Given an actual source IP of `217.70.183.200`, we can see what's happening. Whois tells us that that IP belongs to `gandi.net`, and a lookup for gandi.net's SPF record returns this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:217.70.176.0/21 ip4:217.70.186.186/32 ip4:217.70.186.187/32 ip6:2001:4b98:c::/48 ip6:2001:4b98:dc2:43:216:3eff:fe69:f13/128 ip4:217.70.186.186/32 ip6:2001:4b98:dc2:90:217:70:186:186/128 ptr ?all
```

The first address range listed in there (`ip4:217.70.176.0/21`) covers the `217.70.183.200` address, so I suggest you set your SPF to this, which should solve your problem (and is exactly what I said in option *2* above):

```
v=spf1 a mx include:gandi.net include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful! Unfortunately I tried it, and now mail-tester says I need `v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com ip4:some-ip-address ~all`... unless mail-tester is just wrong?

Comment: No, it just means you're still trying to send from somewhere not covered by your SPF rules. You have not told us where you're sending from, so we can only guess.

Comment: So I've configured my Gmail to send mail on behalf of my Gandi mail servers

Comment: If you can provide a real IP address that you're sending from we might have a hope of diagnosing this.

Comment: Ok sure, now mail_tester is saying: the record SHOULD be `v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com ip4:217.70.183.200 ~all`

Comment: ah ok, sorry i would have given it to you earlier, i just thougth it was pointless because it looked like it kept changing. didn't realize it was helpful. this worked, thanks so much!